# Help reverse engineering PWM Dimmer Flicker-less mod

Tags: led, pwm, dimmer

I've been playing with LEDs for video work for a while. I made some LED panels using strips and off the shelf controllers which always worked nicely while on full brightness. Every time I dim them down, I start to get some weird "scanline" flickering. That happens to all sorts of LEDs and dimmers (Arduino included) I've ever played with.

Yesterday, a friend told me he got a modded 12-24V 8A Dimmer which extinguish this kind of problem. Once I got it in my hands, I was surprised it looked just like a 12-24 Dimmer I got from eBay. Googling around I found out it's a very popular circuit, with MANY different PCB layouts and different vendors.

[image]

I tried to find Flicker related mods online, but couldn't find anything. Obviously I opened his circuit and it's surprisingly similar to mine, apart from 3 differences I spotted:

[image: My friends modded PCB]

I tried to transpose these mods to my PCB. I think I got two of them right (Yellow and Green), but I just can't find where to do the mod which I circled in red (the track that has been interrupted).

[image: My PCB and where I think I should place the mods]

I tried to follow the tracks, but they go underneath the LM358 and the 3-pin connector. The other IC is a 555.

I have two questions regarding this situation, due to my limited electric engineering knowledge:

- Where I should interrupt the board on my PCB Layout?
- What exactly did this MOD do that eliminated the flickering on video?

Here are a few other pics of the boards:

[image: Bottom of friends board]

[image: Bottom of my Board]

Any help or tips are extremely appreciated! Docs and Papers regarding LEDs and Flickering are also welcome :D

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I managed to unsolder the pot connector and the two ICs so I can get a better view of the board. I did destroy one pad on the U1, which apparently didn't connect anything, just the jumped pins.

There's also a solder blob between U1 and the middle pot pin. It's a jumper to rejoin a track I manually cut and repaired afterwards.

[image: Overview]

[image: 758 Side]

[image: 555 Side]

I'll be posting demos of both circuits working, so I can show you the visual difference too.

---

Adding more info I couldn't on my first post:

I edited my tests to show you. Different cameras, but same results. First one is my friend's circuit, 100% flicker free (I had to crop it because there was sensitive content in the frame):

[Flicker Free Circuit](https://vimeo.com/243966287/10ef662cc2)

The little blackouts are just me not being able to hold the supply wires, not circuit faults.

[My Flickery Circuit](https://vimeo.com/243966513/8889308df2)

As you can see, it only stays flicker-free on max power. As soon as you dim out, it starts flickering.

Both tests were powered by a regular 9V battery (not ideal, but it's what I had on hand).

Based on the link pointed out by jsotola, I could gather a few more pieces of info:

- Frequency is governed by the 555 astable. The capacitor between pins 2 and 6 of the 555 should be responsible for that frequency.
- This calculator helps to find the right cap for the frequency I want: [Calculator](http://www.ohmslawcalculator.com/555-astable-calculator)
- Assuming my R1, R2 and C values are respectively 1 kΩ, 10 kΩ and 100 nF, the output frequency should be around 680 Hz, which matches the linked video oscilloscope test. I will try to get one and verify my circuit.
- A comment by brokenmonkey on the same link gave some video related tips:

> I know 6 kHz is a safe frequency for video but it can cause audio interference, and 20 kHz is safe for audio but maybe not all types of video.

Following his logic, replacing C1 with a 11 nF capacitor should do the trick. Still, my friend's circuit has a couple of other things applied, as shown on the images.

My friend was also emphatic that the waveform should be square. I guess it comes from factory that way too...

Thanks again for all the help :D

Comment: "I tried to follow the trails but they go underneath the LM358 and the 3 pinned connector." - you have two choices: 1. remove the part that is obscuring the trace you are trying to follow. 2. Use a continuity tester to look for connections between components.

Comment: found this http://smokedprojects.blogspot.ca/2013/09/led-dimmer-pwm-hack.html

Comment: the cut trace "red" most likely connects to one of the bridged pins "yellow"

Comment: Thank you both!

Ill be looking into the circuit and checking if I can solve it our based on your feedback. 

Unfortunately I wasn't allowed to make changes to my friends PCB and I don't have access to it anymore... It has been shipped abroad :/

Comment: I just remembered do have a broken board back home. Will be unsoldering every component of mine to get a better understanding of the circuit. Will edit my post as soon as I do it!

Comment: Have you been able to find (or create) a schematic for the 12-24v 8A dimmer (the one at the top of your OP) ?  It appears to me that the LM358 opamp compares a reference voltage (set by the potentiometer) to the sawtooth wave generated by the 555, to create a PWM square-wave which controls the output MOSFET.   I don't understand why they needed the opamp, when pin 3 of the 555 gives a square-wave output and the duty cycle can be modulated by putting the pot betwen pins 6 and 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NAILED IT!

As I described on my last post, based on the link suggested by jsotola, replacing the 100nf capacitor with a 11nf capacitor should do the trick. As I didn't have a 11nf, I used a 10nf polyester one and it just did the trick!!!

So yeah, if you are intending to shoot video/digital cinema, try to set the PWM around 6Khz.

Mod picture:
[image: My mod]

PS: notice that I did not apply any of the other mods from my friends unit.

Cheers and again thanks for all the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

These are very poor dimmers.  A decent dimmer will have an inductor and fairly large capacitors to smooth out the flicker.

The dimmers you have just turn the LED power off and on.  As you dim the power is turned off for longer lengths of time.  That is why they flicker.

What you need is an adjustable constant current regulator.
You will need at least a 36V power supply.
You need one driver for each strip.

Inexpensive: [PicoBuck LED Driver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13716), [FemtoBuck LED Driver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13716)

Good quality: [Infineon EVALLED-ILD6150](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-ild6150_60v-AN-v1.1-en.pdf?folderId=db3a30431400ef68011407aaa4500184&fileId=db3a30433cabdd35013cb4b6b6d76cc0)

The easier way is to use a Mean Well HLG-xxH-Cxxxx driver with the strips wired in series.  Which one depends on how many strips and the current required.

Example: 3-5 strips @ 210 - 350mA use a HLG-60H-C350 Type A

---

> Any ideas on what exactly the mod may have done to the circuit?

Really cannot say without schematics and the number of LEDs per strip.  The pictured boards have different circuitry and is doubtful a mod from one will apply to another.

Your mod is somehow changing the shape of the switching waveform. 
Most likely the mod would increase the switching frequency.

With a 24V output you should not drive more than 7 or 8 LEDs in series.

These dimmers turn the LED off and on to regulate the current.  The frequency and duty-cycle have a significant effect on the Stroboscopic Effect. Higher frequency and higher duty-cycle will minimizes the flicker.

The max current will affect the duty cycle. If the max current is too high the duty-cycle must be decreased. When the dimming is at full output and it does not over-drive the LEDs, the duty-cycle may be 99%.  If at full output the current over-drives the LEDs the duty-cycle must be reduced to reduce the current to the max.  Further dimming reduces the duty-cyle further increasing the LED off time (flicker).

[image: duty cycle]

---

**Modulated Dimming**

In this look at the "Signal" as the level of dimming.

### [image: modulation]

White paper: [Understanding Stroboscopic Effects](http://www.xicato.com/sites/default/files/documents/Flicker%20White%20Paper_0.pdf)

IEEE paper: [Designing to Mitigate the Effects of Flicker in LED Lighting](http://bio-licht.org/02_resources/info_ieee-pem_2014-09_led-flickering.pdf)

US Dept. of Energy paper: [What You Need to Know about LED Flicker and Dimming](https://www1.eere.energy.gov/buildings/publications/pdfs/ssl/poplawski_dimming_lightfair2012.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! Im aware that they are cheap stuff. Unfortunately that's what I could get one day before my film shooting down here in Brazil.

These FemtoBuck Led drivers looks nice, I'll be getting a couple of both to perform some tests.

Still, I shot the filme using my friend dimmers (which unfortunately are already abroad) and indeed it completely solved the flickering issues (shooting ag 23.976fps, 1/48).

Any ideas on what exactly the mod may have done to the circuit? 

Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! I managed to unsold the 2 ICs and the potentiometer conector, updated my post.

Actually, I'm driving single 10W leds. Will be looking more carefully into your information!

Thanks again!